# Secure individual Apache folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, directory

I have an apache server running on my PC. In the main directory, I have two folders: A public folder and a private folder. I would like people to be able to access the public folder, but not the private folder. I made a password file and correctly linked it to and htaccess file and put the htaccess file inside of the private folder. However, when I open the server on my browser, the private folder is not visible at all. Can anyone help? I just want the private folder secured.

Comment: Can anyone please help?? Usually I get answers within like 10 minutes. This server is for my software team, and I need it up ASAP.

Comment: Someone please help!!!!!